# A closed subspace of a separable Hilbert Space is Separable

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert Space which is separable. Let $Y$ be a closed Subspace of $X$. I need to show that $Y$ is separable.

Since $X$ is separable it has a countable dense subset say $M$. Taking the help from the hint suggested, for every $m \in M$, there exists a unique $y$ in $Y$ such that $d(m,Y)=||y-m||$. So I define a map $P:M\to Y$ such that $p(m)=y$ for which  $d(m,Y)=||y-m||$. This is well defined. Now $S=\{p(m)|m \in M\}$. Now I claim that $\bar{S}=Y$. Let $y_0 \in Y$. Let $r \gt 0$.Then since $\bar{M}=X$, there exists $m_0\in M$ such that $||m_0-y_0|| \lt r$. Corresponding to $m_0$, there exists a unique $P(m_0) \in Y$ such that $||m_0-Y||=||m_0-p(m_0)|| \le ||m_0-y_0|| \lt r$.

And we are done. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: An example where the interestion would be empty is $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $M=\mathbb{Q}^2$ and $Y=\{(x,\pi x) : x\in \mathbb{R} \}\subset X$.

Comment: A metric space is separable if and only if it is second countable. And a (topological) subspace of a second countable space is second countable. Alternatively, take an orthonormal basis of $Y$. Extending it to an orthonormal basis of $X$ shows that it is countable, hence $Y$ is separable.

Comment: @DanielFischer.. I thought of using this but forgot the if and only if condition of the metric space. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the fact that $X/Y^{\perp} \cong Y$, and the quotient of a separable space is clearly separable.

Comment: A Hilbert space is separable iff it has a countable complete orthonormal basis. Take an orthonormal basis of $Y$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis of $X$. It follows that the orthonormal basis of $Y$ must be countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of a countable dense subset $M$ with the subspace $Y$ can be empty. A possibility would be to project $M$ onto $Y$ (i.e., choosing
$p(x)\in Y$ such that $\|p(x)-x\| \le \|y-x\|$ for all $y\in Y$) and then show that $\lbrace p(x):x\in M\rbrace$ is dense.