# How to prove that $\{f_n\}$ is dense in $Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Following this question: [A closed subspace of a separable Hilbert Space is Separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409030/a-closed-subspace-of-a-separable-hilbert-space-is-separable)

> Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert Space which is separable. Let $Y$ be a closed Subspace of $X$. I need to show that $Y$ is separable.

Let $\{e_k\}$ be an (countable) orthonormal basis of $X$ and let $\{f_n\}$ be the projection of $\{e_n\}$ on $Y$. That is take projection $f:=P_{Y} e_n$. Here it is enough to prove $\{f_n\}$ is a countable dense subset of $Y$.

Countable is clearly. But how to show that $\{f_n\}$ is dense? That means for every $\epsilon>0$, for any $y\in Y$, there is $f\in \{f_n\}$ so that
$$
\|y-f\|\le \epsilon...
$$

I am stuck here and I do not know how to use "closed" property of $Y$?

Comment: $\{f_n\}$ is *not* dense. Don't take an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ of $X$ but (like in the linked page) a countable *dense* subset $M\subset X.$

Comment: This doesn't work on $X$ itself.

Comment: Any subset of a separable metric space is separable.

Comment: @geetha290krm I guess maybe the idea for this problem is that if the subspace is closed, you can avoid using countable axiom of choice by having an explicit construction through projections, so you get something true in $ZF$.

Comment: Although, regarding my last comment, you apparently have to really get into the weeds a bit and muck around with the definition of completeness in order to get the Hilbert projection theorem without using countable choice (see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1483241/1210477 ), so that might not be the intent of this problem after all.

Comment: If you are eager to use orthonormal basis let $B_Y$ be an orthonormal basis of $Y.$ Then it can be extended to an orthonormal basis $B_X$ of $X.$ By separability of $X$ the set $B_X$ is countable so is its subset $B_Y.$ Hence $Y$ is separable.

Comment: Hermi, there was no need to edit a new question: the post you linked to did answer your question [A closed subspace of a separable Hilbert Space is Separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409030/a-closed-subspace-of-a-separable-hilbert-space-is-separable) and gave you these two methods (the one in my first comment and the other one in the previous comment by Ryszard). Please read it more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you starting with a countable orthonormal basis? All you know is that $X$ is separable, so it has a countable dense subset. Then it suffices to show/use that for $y\in Y$ that $|y-p(x)|\leq |y-x|+|p(x)-x|\leq 2|y-x|$, so $x_i$ being dense in X implies $p(x_i)$ is dense in Y.

Closed is necessary for the definition of the projection to be definable though it isn’t necessary for the general theorem.